Problem with typescript TS2322: Type 'ForwardedRef<HTMLElement>
I have the following code taken directly from https://codesandbox.io/ the case is mantegnous/test-dnd-kit
when testing in codesandbox it works well.
I make a new create-react-app and install the necessary libraries:
"@dnd-kit/core": "^6.1.0",
"@dnd-kit/sortable": "^8.0.0",
"@dnd-kit/utilities": "^3.2.2",
But I receive the following error:
TS2322: Type 'ForwardedRef<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type '((string | ((instance: HTMLButtonElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLButtonElement>) & (string | ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) | RefObject<...>)) | null | undefined'.
  Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | null>' is not assignable to type '((string | ((instance: HTMLButtonElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLButtonElement>) & (string | ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) | RefObject<...>)) | null | undefined'.
    Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | null>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLButtonElement> & RefObject<HTMLDivElement>'.
      Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | null>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLButtonElement>'.
        Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
          Type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLButtonElement | null'.
            Type 'HTMLElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLButtonElement': disabled, form, formAction, formEnctype, and 13 more.


in the file Container.tsx. The line is emphasized with ****.
import React, { forwardRef } from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";

import { Handle } from "../Handle";
import { Remove } from "../Remove";

import styles from "./Container.module.css";

export interface Props  {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  columns?: number;
  label?: string;
  style?: React.CSSProperties;
  horizontal?: boolean;
  hover?: boolean;
  handleProps?: React.HTMLAttributes<any>;
  scrollable?: boolean;
  shadow?: boolean;
  placeholder?: boolean;
  unstyled?: boolean;
  onClick?(): void;
  onRemove?(): void;
}

export const Container = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, Props>(
  (
    {
      children,
      columns = 1,
      handleProps,
      horizontal,
      hover,
      onClick,
      onRemove,
      label,
      placeholder,
      style,
      scrollable,
      shadow,
      unstyled,
      ...props
    }: Props,
    ref
  ) => {
    const Component = onClick ? "button" : "div";

    return (
      <Component
        {...props}
        ****ref={ref}****
        style={
          {
            ...style,
            "--columns": columns
          } as React.CSSProperties
        }
        className={classNames(
          styles.Container,
          unstyled && styles.unstyled,
          horizontal && styles.horizontal,
          hover && styles.hover,
          placeholder && styles.placeholder,
          scrollable && styles.scrollable,
          shadow && styles.shadow
        )}
        onClick={onClick}
        tabIndex={onClick ? 0 : undefined}
      >
        {label ? (
          <div className={styles.Header}>
            {label}
            <div className={styles.Actions}>
              {onRemove ? <Remove onClick={onRemove} /> : undefined}
              <Handle {...handleProps} />
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : null}
        {placeholder ? children : <ul>{children}</ul>}
      </Component>
    );
  }
);


full stack trace:
S2322: Type 'ForwardedRef<HTMLDivElement | HTMLElement | HTMLButtonElement>' is not assignable to type '((string | ((instance: HTMLButtonElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLButtonElement>) & (string | ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) | RefObject<...>)) | null | undefined'.
  Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | HTMLElement | HTMLButtonElement | null>' is not assignable to type '((string | ((instance: HTMLButtonElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLButtonElement>) & (string | ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) | RefObject<...>)) | null | undefined'.
    Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | HTMLElement | HTMLButtonElement | null>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLButtonElement> & RefObject<HTMLDivElement>'.
      Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | HTMLElement | HTMLButtonElement | null>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLButtonElement>'.
        Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
          Type 'HTMLDivElement | HTMLElement | HTMLButtonElement | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLButtonElement | null'.
            Type 'HTMLDivElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLButtonElement': disabled, form, formAction, formEnctype, and 13 more.
    48 |       <Component
    49 |         {...props}
  > 50 |         ref={ref}
       |         ^^^
    51 |         style={
    52 |           {
    53 |             ...style,


How do I solve this problem? I have tried several solutions found on the net but nothing solves my problem.
Thanks for any hints.

****ref={ref}****  please use valid code syntax. Use comment formatting to indicate areas of interest

Since Component can be a div or a button, I think you may just need to update the forwardRef to forwardRef<HTMLDivElement | HTMLButtonElement, Props>

@RCB thanks for your input but it didn't seem to solve the problem. I have updated my questioin with the full stack trace.
